# R: How to get a dataset with blanks in its name

Tags: r, dataset, names

How can one get an R dataset with blanks in its name, such as
'BJsales.lead (BJsales)' in package "datasets" ?

```
pkg = "datasets"
cat( "Summary of all the datasets in package", pkg, "--\n"  )
d = data( package=pkg ) $results  # "Package" "LibPath" "Item" "Title"
names = d[ , "Item" ]
titles = d[ , "Title" ]
    # sum( duplicated( names )) ??

for( j in 1:len(names) ){
    name = names[[j]]
    cat( name, ":\n" )

    data( list=name )
    x = get( name )  # <-- Error if blank in name

    m = paste( dim( as.matrix( x )), collapse=" " )  # grr
    cat( class(x), m, " freq", frequency(x), "\n" )
}

# -> Error in get(name) : object 'BJsales.lead (BJsales)' not found
```

OK, `get` can only lookup valid names, that's reasonable.
But what to do -- how can one get the data for 'BJsales.lead (BJsales)' ?

R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.8.3 (Mountain Lion)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you just want to examine the dataset or are you trying to save it as another object name? Nothing you're doing here really seems necessary to access a dataset (which can just be done with `data()`).

Comment: @Thomas, I want a "Summary of all the datasets in package X". If you try it, though, you see that `data(name); get(name)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, `get()` *can* look up "invalid" names:

```
`x y` <- 3;
get('x y');
## [1] 3
```

The issue here is that the `Item` column of the `results` matrix returned by `data()` does not always contain the exact name of the data set; in some cases, it has a parenthetical suffix, although I've no idea why.

You can strip it off with `gsub()`, and then loading via `get()` should work.

Also, you shouldn't need the `data(list=name)` call.

Also, there's no `len()` (unfortunately); I think you mean `length()`.

Hence:

```
pkg <- 'datasets';
cat('Summary of all the datasets in package',pkg,'--\n');

d <- data(package=pkg)$results; # 'Package' 'LibPath' 'Item' 'Title'
names <- d[,'Item'];
titles <- d[,'Title'];

for (j in 1:length(names)) {
    name <- names[j];
    cat(name,':\n');
    x <- get(gsub('\\s.*','',name));
    m <- paste(dim(as.matrix(x)),collapse=' ');
    cat(class(x),m,' freq',frequency(x),'\n');
};
## Summary of all the datasets in package datasets --
## AirPassengers :
## ts 144 1  freq 12
## BJsales :
## ts 150 1  freq 1
## BJsales.lead (BJsales) :
## ts 150 1  freq 1
## BOD :
## data.frame 6 2  freq 1
## CO2 :
## nfnGroupedData nfGroupedData groupedData data.frame 84 5  freq 1
## ChickWeight :
## nfnGroupedData nfGroupedData groupedData data.frame 578 4  freq 1
## DNase :
## nfnGroupedData nfGroupedData groupedData data.frame 176 3  freq 1
## EuStockMarkets :
## mts ts matrix 1860 4  freq 260
## Formaldehyde :
## data.frame 6 2  freq 1
## HairEyeColor :
## table 32 1  freq 1
## Harman23.cor :
## list 3 1  freq 1
## Harman74.cor :
## list 3 1  freq 1
## Indometh :
## nfnGroupedData nfGroupedData groupedData data.frame 66 3  freq 1
## InsectSprays :
## data.frame 72 2  freq 1
## JohnsonJohnson :
## ts 84 1  freq 4
## LakeHuron :
## ts 98 1  freq 1
## LifeCycleSavings :
## data.frame 50 5  freq 1
## Loblolly :
## nfnGroupedData nfGroupedData groupedData data.frame 84 3  freq 1
## Nile :
## ts 100 1  freq 1
## Orange :
## nfnGroupedData nfGroupedData groupedData data.frame 35 3  freq 1
## OrchardSprays :
## data.frame 64 4  freq 1
## PlantGrowth :
## data.frame 30 2  freq 1
## Puromycin :
## data.frame 23 3  freq 1
## Seatbelts :
## mts ts 192 8  freq 12
## Theoph :
## nfnGroupedData nfGroupedData groupedData data.frame 132 5  freq 1
## Titanic :
## table 32 1  freq 1
## ToothGrowth :
## data.frame 60 3  freq 1
## UCBAdmissions :
## table 24 1  freq 1
## UKDriverDeaths :
## ts 192 1  freq 12
## UKgas :
## ts 108 1  freq 4
## USAccDeaths :
## ts 72 1  freq 12
## USArrests :
## data.frame 50 4  freq 1
## USJudgeRatings :
## data.frame 43 12  freq 1
## USPersonalExpenditure :
## matrix 5 5  freq 1
## VADeaths :
## matrix 5 4  freq 1
## WWWusage :
## ts 100 1  freq 1
## WorldPhones :
## matrix 7 7  freq 1
## ability.cov :
## list 3 1  freq 1
## airmiles :
## ts 24 1  freq 1
## airquality :
## data.frame 153 6  freq 1
## anscombe :
## data.frame 11 8  freq 1
## attenu :
## data.frame 182 5  freq 1
## attitude :
## data.frame 30 7  freq 1
## austres :
## ts 89 1  freq 4
## beaver1 (beavers) :
## data.frame 114 4  freq 1
## beaver2 (beavers) :
## data.frame 100 4  freq 1
## cars :
## data.frame 50 2  freq 1
## chickwts :
## data.frame 71 2  freq 1
## co2 :
## ts 468 1  freq 12
## crimtab :
## table 42 22  freq 1
## discoveries :
## ts 100 1  freq 1
## esoph :
## data.frame 88 5  freq 1
## euro :
## numeric 11 1  freq 1
## euro.cross (euro) :
## matrix 11 11  freq 1
## eurodist :
## dist 21 21  freq 1
## faithful :
## data.frame 272 2  freq 1
## fdeaths (UKLungDeaths) :
## ts 72 1  freq 12
## freeny :
## data.frame 39 5  freq 1
## freeny.x (freeny) :
## matrix 39 4  freq 1
## freeny.y (freeny) :
## ts 39 1  freq 4
## infert :
## data.frame 248 8  freq 1
## iris :
## data.frame 150 5  freq 1
## iris3 :
## array 600 1  freq 1
## islands :
## numeric 48 1  freq 1
## ldeaths (UKLungDeaths) :
## ts 72 1  freq 12
## lh :
## ts 48 1  freq 1
## longley :
## data.frame 16 7  freq 1
## lynx :
## ts 114 1  freq 1
## mdeaths (UKLungDeaths) :
## ts 72 1  freq 12
## morley :
## data.frame 100 3  freq 1
## mtcars :
## data.frame 32 11  freq 1
## nhtemp :
## ts 60 1  freq 1
## nottem :
## ts 240 1  freq 12
## npk :
## data.frame 24 5  freq 1
## occupationalStatus :
## table 8 8  freq 1
## precip :
## numeric 70 1  freq 1
## presidents :
## ts 120 1  freq 4
## pressure :
## data.frame 19 2  freq 1
## quakes :
## data.frame 1000 5  freq 1
## randu :
## data.frame 400 3  freq 1
## rivers :
## numeric 141 1  freq 1
## rock :
## data.frame 48 4  freq 1
## sleep :
## data.frame 20 3  freq 1
## stack.loss (stackloss) :
## numeric 21 1  freq 1
## stack.x (stackloss) :
## matrix 21 3  freq 1
## stackloss :
## data.frame 21 4  freq 1
## state.abb (state) :
## character 50 1  freq 1
## state.area (state) :
## numeric 50 1  freq 1
## state.center (state) :
## list 2 1  freq 1
## state.division (state) :
## factor 50 1  freq 1
## state.name (state) :
## character 50 1  freq 1
## state.region (state) :
## factor 50 1  freq 1
## state.x77 (state) :
## matrix 50 8  freq 1
## sunspot.month :
## ts 3177 1  freq 12
## sunspot.year :
## ts 289 1  freq 1
## sunspots :
## ts 2820 1  freq 12
## swiss :
## data.frame 47 6  freq 1
## treering :
## ts 7980 1  freq 1
## trees :
## data.frame 31 3  freq 1
## uspop :
## ts 19 1  freq 0.1
## volcano :
## matrix 87 61  freq 1
## warpbreaks :
## data.frame 54 3  freq 1
## women :
## data.frame 15 2  freq 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why "data(list=name)" is unnecessary -- `data(package=pkg)` puts say 100 names in some namespace ? but the actual data, which could be 100 x 1G, is loaded ... when ?  Also, how come  `duplicated(names )` ?

Comment: The `datasets` package is loaded automatically in every R session; you can see this in `search()`. Data sets from other packages are *not* loaded automatically, but to load them, you have to load the package itself, e.g. `library('ggplot2')` to get the `mpg` data set. Running `data(package=whatever)` doesn't actually load any data sets; it just returns information about data sets.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about `duplicated(names)`; there are no duplicates.

Comment: Re duplicated:  running exactly your script (in 3.1.3  on macosx 10.8.3) I get everything twice ?? Log is in https://gist.github.com/denis-bz/a5a2a34575a5e16d2bbc

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Not sure what the culprit is; on my system there are no duplicates. Your R installation might have duplicate data on disk. Maybe try looking into the source of the `data()` function to see how it builds its result. From a quick scan, maybe see what `find.package('datasets')` returns, and how it proceeds from there.

Comment: Are you also 3.1.3 ? Don't want to take up any more of your time (nor mine)  but if you know any gurus who might know, please forward, thanks.

Comment: Yep, R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09). Don't know any gurus, good luck.